# Can't boot USB thumbdrive, same image works on USB HD

Tags: usb-storage, arch-linux

I put Arch Linux on a USB thumbdrive and cannot boot it.  The same image boots on my USB HD.

The problem I get while booting the USB thumbdrive is UDEV waiting for events.  It eventually fails and a bunch of other services also fail, some saying i/o error (and nothing else).

I ran badblocks on the USB thumbdrive and found nothing.

Is this an I/O issue?  The USB thumbdrive is literally brand-spanking new.

Comment: What did you use to put the image in the thumb drive?  You have to use something like Unetbootin to get a thumb drive to boot Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newest version of ArchISO solves my problem.  It boots every time now.